# Threshold between failed attempts to read a message with Spring cloud SqsListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, listener, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

In my Spring-Boot 2 app there's a `SqsListener`:

```java
@SqsListener(value = "${sqs.message.queue}", deletionPolicy = ON_SUCCESS)
public void myMessageListener(MyMessage myMessage) throws MyMessageServiceException {
    myMessageService.processMessage(myMessage);
}
```

`MyMessageService#processMessage` throws exceptions in some cases. When it does, the message returns to SQS, as commanded by `deletionPolicy`, to be read again by aforementioned listener.

I want to have some kind of threshold (say, 600 seconds) between failed attempts to process the message.

Is there an out-of-the-box solution to set up this kind of threshold without creating some circuit breaker logic?

Answer (score 0):

The only "code-less" solution I've come up with is to change the `Default visibility timeout` property in SQS queue settings in Amazon SQS Management Console.